# Content-type set to text/plain in Chrome version 84 Browser online vs application/javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, tomcat

With the latest Chrome Browser, we are seeing an issue with Javascripts files response headers content-type to text/plain rather setting as application/javascript. It was working till previous versions of chrome at the same time it works in firefox. Same case working in PROD but fails in QA ... Anybody had this issue? is there any specific Tomcat or Apache configurations needed.

More Context...

We have spring based applications with javascript files that need to be loaded the first time. We use static file cache feature in the spring to cache and render javascript files. All are working fine from years, all of a sudden with the latest Chrome 84 version we are seeing that javascript files are not getting loaded. The error says Strict Mime-type text/plain cant run in the chrome console... but it works fine in monster at the same time... Default mimetype from apache webserver is text/plain.

Is there any specific configuration in Tomcat or Apache to enforce mimetype to application/javascript in the response

Comment: Can you add more context to your question?

Comment: editted the original message